# Suppress Vagrant shell provisioning output

Tags: shell, vagrant

When using [Vagrant's shell provisioning](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) is there a way to suppress the output? Here is what I've tried:

```
su vagrant -l -c "nvm install v0.10.12" > /dev/null
su vagrant -l -c "nvm install v0.10.12 > /dev/null"
```

Neither of those work. I'm wanting to suppress the output, so that I don't have over a 1,000 lines of:

```
#######################################################################   99.8%
#######################################################################   99.9%
#######################################################################   99.9%
#######################################################################   99.9%
#######################################################################  100.0%
#######################################################################  100.0%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little more googling, NIXCRAFT's ["BASH Shell Redirect Output and Errors To /dev/null"](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/) article provided the answer:

```
su vagrant -l -c "nvm install v0.10.12 > /dev/null 2>&1"
```